# How to set a node of an XML file?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, dom

I've created an XML document.

So, now, I want to find the good node and set the values of this node, but after any research about this topic, I don't know how to do it.

This is my document :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scripts>
  <script nom="myTools.class.php">
    <titre>Useful php classes</titre>
    <date>18/07/2011</date>
    <options>
      <option name="topic">Tutorials</option>
      <option name="desc">Tutorial for you</option>
    </options>
  </script>
  <script nom="index.php">
    <titre>blabla</titre>
    <date>15/07/2011</date>
    <options>
     <option name="topic">The homepage</option>
    </options>
  </script>
</scripts
```

>

So, I would to build an html form with theses values, but at this moment, I can't get and set that I want :(

I want get the first "script" node :

```
  <script nom="myTools.class.php"> //How to set the "nom" attribute ?
    <titre>Useful php classes</titre> //How to get this value and set it ?
    <date>18/07/2011</date>
    <options>
      <option name="topic">Tutorials</option>
      <option name="desc">Tutorial for you</option>
    </options>
  </script>
```

I have no problem to loop all the document, but not with only my "own choices"

Have you an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use XPath 
first get the dom document

```
$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML('file');  // file is the name of XML file if u have a string of XML called $string then use $dom->loadXML($string)
$xpath=new DOMXPath($dom);
$path='//scripts/script[1]';  // that would get the first node
$elem=$xpath->query($path);
```

now $`elem[0]` is your first script node

if u want to get elements by their attribute then use `$path='//scripts/script[@nom='attribute value']';`
now using this path will return a nodeset with script elements having a nom attribute of ur given value 
you can see more here

---

in response to `bahamut100`'s comment
the xpath fot the option element is `//options/option`

now if u meant getting an option node by attribute value then do this

```
$path='//options/option[@attrib_name=attrib_value]';
$elem=$xpath->query($path);
```

but if u meant getting the attributes of a node then first u have to reach that node. in ur case u have to reach to the option node first

```
$path='//options/option';
$option=$xpath->query($path);
```

now `$option` is a node list
so for getting the first element's attibutes use

```
$attribute=$option[0]->attributes;
```

now $attribute is a NamedNodeMap so for getting the value of first attribute use

```
$value=$attribute->item(0);
```

Comment: Thank, but How to access at the attribute of "options" node ?

Comment: u want to get the attribute value or get option node by attribute value? i am writing that in my answer

Answer (score 0):

[XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) is one way of doing it:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML(... your xml here ...);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$results = $xp->query('//script[@nom='myTools.class.php']/titre');

$old_title = $results[0]->nodeValue;
$results[0]->nodeValue = 'New title here';
```